# How can I do two countifs criteria while using importrange?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, counting, countif, importrange

How can I use two criterias for countifs while using importrange and sum? This one gives me and error.

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg/edit#gid=328894125","Furniture Campaign!H:H")),"Legal - CSA CUL*","Furniture Campaign!M:M","Pending QA/Upload"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be either:

```
=COUNTIFS(
 IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg", "Furniture Campaign!H:H"), 
 "Legal - CSA CUL*",
 IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg", "Furniture Campaign!M:M"), 
 "Pending QA/Upload")
```

or:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIF(
     IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg", "Furniture Campaign!H:H"), 
     "Legal - CSA CUL*")),
     IFERROR(COUNTIF(
     IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg", "Furniture Campaign!M:M"), 
     "Pending QA/Upload")))
```

Comment: player0 can you exlain a bit? like the difference of our code. thanks though it worked!

Comment: sure, you either want to use countifs or sum two countif functions. also make sure you have allowed access

Comment: I have used the first one. It's correct. The second one is not giving the right value.

Comment: I haven't done much sumif with two countif functions. So how do I do this? If without importrange, this is my code ```=SUMIF('Decor Campaign'!H:H,"Regular Campaign*",'Decor Campaign'!L:L)```
However, if I'll do with importrange, how to do it? H:HRegular Campaign is the criteria, and L:L is the range to sum.

Comment: SUMIF wont do. you will need to use SUM(IF( combo

Comment: I am not sure how it's done. I have done this ```=SUM(IF(IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ/edit#gid=359656787","HIP Campaign!H:H")H:H = "Regular Campaign*"),"HIP Campaign!L:L")```

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHtKxsygTlx-07pCKx5d-L5waZCaK3J-VLez3UFqYhM/edit?usp=sharing] here it is

Comment: The formula you have provided just now didn't work.

Comment: It's no longer an error but wrong value. 208,883 instead of 75,461

Comment: wrap it all into ArrayFormula()